# Как именно ВЫ поступайте с input[type='tel]?

Tags: html, вёрстка, input

у меня вопрос по поводу формы и тега input[type='tel']. Как вы делайте его что бы при заполнение был правильный формат. К примеру как делает inputMask но проблема данного плагина в том что для него можно ставить одну маску и к примеру если у человека номер не начинается с +7 как для жителей России он не может ввести свой номер. Каким образом лучше всего сделать данный тег, какой pattern используйте или какие хитрости для облегчение правильности ввода номера( Placeholder - пожалуйста не советуйте )

Comment: код региона не обязан входить в маску. Лучше формат не ограничивать, а просто проверять ввод, на правильность, одним регулярным выражением будет тяжело обойтись, если вообще возможно

Comment: Для проверки на правильность номера можно воспользоваться например библиотекой от гугл: [libphonenumber](https://github.com/googlei18n/libphonenumber)